# Unable to install swirl package in R

Tags: r, swirl

when I type install.packages(''swirl) , I got the following error.

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Tanvir ahmed/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

There is a binary version available but the source
version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
swirl  2.4.3  2.4.5             FALSE

installing the source package ‘swirl’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/swirl_2.4.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 108847 bytes (106 KB)
downloaded 106 KB

- installing *source* package 'swirl' ...
  ** package 'swirl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  there is no package called 'bitops'
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'swirl'
- removing 'C:/Users/Tanvir ahmed/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/swirl'
  Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Tanvir ahmed\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\TANVIR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpywcBFw/downloaded_packages/swirl_2.4.5.tar.gz' had status 1
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘swirl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\Tanvir ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpywcBFw\downloaded_packages’

How can I fix the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it pop up a message asking if you wanted to install from source? What did you say? I'd suggest you stick to the binary version. `install.packages(''swirl", type="binary")` Aslo are you really running R 3.4? I might also suggest that you update your R to a more recent version R 4.0.2 is out now.

Comment: You can also try installing the missing dependency with `install.packages("bitops")`

Comment: My R version is 3.4.1 and I am using the latest RStudio version.@MrFlick